# $n$-th derivatives and Taylor series of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ around $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am trying to write down Taylor's series of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ around $0$.

After few computations, what I arrived at is: if $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, then
$$
f(0)=1, \,\,\, f'(0)=0, \,\,\, f^{(2)}(0)=-1, \,\,\, f^{(3)}(0)=1, \,\, f^{(4)}(0)=0, \ldots,
$$
So, for the derivatives at $0$, pattern looking is $(1,0,-1,1,0,-1,\ldots)$; but, I want to determine by some tools the explicit formula for $n$-th derivative at $0$. Any trick here is applicable?

Comment: Actually, $f^{(4)}(0)=-3$.

Comment: oho, sorry! ?Its my mistake in computation. I rechecked it. (But I couldn't find any simpler way to proceed for $n$-th derivative at $0$).

Comment: It's $f^{(2n)}(0)=-(2n-3)!!\,(2n-1)!!$ for $n\ge2$, the odd derivatives are $0$.

Comment: The pattern cannot be $1,0,-1$ periodically, because that would correspond to the entire series

$$1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\cdots -x^2(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\cdots)$$ which is

$$(1-x^2)\frac1{1-x^3}=\frac{1+x}{1+x+x^2}.$$

You cannot generalize from so few terms.

Comment: Write the expansion of $\sqrt{1+z}$ and then plug $z=-x^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following way which is probably easier than finding a closed expression for $f^{(n)}(x)$. Take $g(x) = \sqrt{1+x}$. Inspecting a couple of derivatives, you can come up with the expression
$$
g^{(n)}(x) = (1+x)^{1/2-n}\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{2}-i\right)
$$
which you might check by induction. The Taylor series of $g$ around $x_0=0$ is then given by
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\prod\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} \left(\frac{1}{2}-i\right)}{k!}x^k.
$$
From here you get your series by replacing $x$ by $-x^2$. (Note that the empty product takes the value 1 by convention).

EDIT: From this expansion you can of course find an explicit expression for $f^{(n)}(0)$.